# Is EntityManager injected with @PersistenceContext to a @RequestScoped CDI bean thread-safe?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, cdi

In a Java EE web application project, there is a DAO annotated as a CDI bean:

```
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerDAO {
  @PersistentContext
  private EntityManager em;
  //some persistence operation afterwards
  @Transactional
  public void update() {
  //implementation using the injected em
  }
}
```

The injected `EntityManager` is not thread-safe according to JPA spec, but the **Question** is:

Is the injection of `EntityManager` into this per request `@RequestScoped` CDI bean thread-safe? and if it is not thread-safe, what potential concurrency issues there might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is shared across threads if you think about it, entity manager is injected in request scope and released after request is done but if you have concurrency doubts use Multiversion concurrency control.

Comment: What is Multiversion concurrency control?

Comment: https://dip-mazumder.medium.com/concurrency-control-in-java-persistence-api-jpa-with-hibernate-optimistic-vs-d74bb50fe4ec look for optimistic locking  part

Comment: I see, you mean the optimistic locking of JPA :) then what if this `CustomAO` is `@ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: Lets think and find out Application scoped bean going to inject Entity manager and then will use that em for every call What you think gonna happen?

Comment: then seems that developers will have to handle synchronization themselves?

Comment: false :D since jakarta ee containers use em proxy instead of real entity manager you are safe :D imagine suprise when i found out this.

Comment: Does this mean you can relax? Again no, Because per specification it is legal to give same entity manager again you need to make sure what your container actually does but if you ask me don't use it and lose the all mental burden. your code will be more readable and portable.  But know that if you use Application scope most probably your container will make it thread safe. All the ones i know does so.

Comment: but `EntityManager` is not thread-safe according to the JPA spec. Only EJB spec told clearly that invocation of methods on EJB are serialized, but `CDI` spec didn't tell such or guarantee such thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256980/discussion-between-ebuzer-taha-kanat-and-rui).